# python could not install any script

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7

I installed `python` from `brew`

```
brew install python
```

then installed pip

```
sudo easy_install pip
```

in Terminal

```
$ which easy_install
/usr/bin/easy_install

$ which python
/usr/bin/python
```

But then when I want to install any Python script I get this:

```
Searching for pexpect
Best match: pexpect 4.2.1
Adding pexpect 4.2.1 to easy-install.pth file

Using /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
Processing dependencies for pexpect
Finished processing dependencies for pexpect
Searching for pycrypto
Best match: pycrypto 2.6.1
pycrypto 2.6.1 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Using /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
Processing dependencies for pycrypto
Finished processing dependencies for pycrypto
Searching for pyopenssl
Best match: pyOpenSSL 0.13.1
pyOpenSSL 0.13.1 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Using /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python
Processing dependencies for pyopenssl
Finished processing dependencies for pyopenssl
Searching for pefile
Best match: pefile 2017.9.3
pefile 2017.9.3 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Using /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
Processing dependencies for pefile
Finished processing dependencies for pefile
```

Here's an image of the problem:

[image]

Comment: When you `brew install python`, you should use the `pip` installed into `/usr/local/bin` or whatever your `brew --prefix` is. Also, `easy_install` is obsolete and should generally never be used (unless necessary).

Comment: $ which pip
/usr/local/bin/pip